# CSV Import to MySQL with PHP skip duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a PHP script that imports a csv into a MySQL database.  The import works fine using this line of code

```
$query = "insert into $databasetable values('$linemysql');";
```

The only problem is when I try to import another csv with duplicates the script errors out.  How do I adjust this script to skip duplicates if they exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INSERT IGNORE` won't insert a row if that would result in a duplicate key. However, it will also ignore (and not generate an error) some other cases like trying to insert `NULL` into a column with `NOT NULL` constraint.

If you just want to ignore duplicates but still get other insert errors, use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead. This will update rows with duplicating keys, although comes with some performance cost.

Comment: didn't know about those keywords +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using mysql try:

```
$query = "insert ignore into $databasetable values('$linemysql');";
```